# Read a tag attribute or a namespace into a Nifi flowfile attribute

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a flow file that begins similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a:foo xmlns:b="whatever"
       d:bar="eleven">
```

I'd like to be able to set an attribute on the flow file to be the value that is "eleven".  I tried using EvaluteXPath and setting an attribute called "foo" to be //*:foo/@d:bar but that didn't seem to work.

Is it possible to grab the value of d:bar into an attribute using EvaluateXPath or some other way?

I can't simply delete the d: from d:bar because the flow file is provided to me by another process and I have no say in how the data comes to me.

Comment: as i remember EvaluateXPath does not support namespaces. so, try something like this: `/foo/@bar` as xpath

Comment: What do you mean "as xpath" ?

Comment: for [EvaluateXPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateXPath/) you could specify dynamic properties where the value should be XPath expression